# Styling a Region

Tags: regions

How do you style a Region, eg with different colours? In all the examples in the help files, they are always blue. It is also very confusing - are they a Graphics3D object, or what exactly are they?

```
p1 = Normalize[{1, 0, 0}]; 
p2 = Normalize[{0, 1, 0}]; 
p3 = Normalize[{0, 0, 1}]; v = t1*p1 + t2*p2 + t3*p3; 
myCone = ParametricRegion[{v,Dot[v, v] == 1 && t1 >= 0 && t2 >= 0 && t3 >= 0}, {t1, t2, t3}]; 
Region[myCone]
```

Comment: See the 'Options' tab in the docs for `Region` - `BaseStyle`, and `Lighting` will probably be helpful.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks. Nevertheless, I still do not know what a "Region" actually is. Is it a computer implementation of a "subset of points"? If it is a set, howcome it gets displayed as a graphics object? If it is a graphics object, what properties of graphics objects does it "inherit"? I do not understand the hierarchy.

Comment: @BruceBartlett yes, it is a set of points, but this set may be possible to visualize, especially if it is a set of points that arises from some geometric constraint. When rendered, it is converted into a normal `Graphics3D` object so it has all of the properties of one. Consider `RegionProduct[Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]] // Region`: this is not rendered as a 4D region cannot be rendered, but is still a `Region` object.

Comment: Ok,I see, thank you.